# Oracle CREATE TYPE and PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

We have an Oracle type that's declared as such:

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE its_accountarray;

There is no base type. This type is then used in Procedures and packages (and in Java Stored procedures as an array descriptor). In the procedure/package it uses **extend** function to add to array.

```
<declare section>
    v_account latax.ITS_ACCOUNTARRAY := new ITS_accountArray();
...
BEGIN
    ...
    ...
    v_account.extend(1);
```

and in Java, it's used as:
    oracle.sql.ARRAY ls_accountARRAY, ls_periodARRAY;

```
oracle.sql.ArrayDescriptor ad =   ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor(**"ITS_ACCOUNTARRAY"**, oconn);

ls_accountARRAY = new ARRAY(ad, oconn, arg_accounts);
ocs.setARRAY(2, ls_accountARRAY);
```

I am curious as to how this works. Even though the name has Array in it, it is not defined as an array or table type, like I typically see. It works, but is this a legal usage or should I declare the type to be of some array type explicitly?

Thanks

Sam

Comment: **Update:** I just want to correct this for anyone stumbling on this question: This turned out to be just a display problem in the Sqltools version I was using. When I edited the type, it was actually displaying the source partially as 
`CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE its_accountarray`

That's what got me. The body portion "**AS TABLE OF...**" was not displayed; apparently it put a lot of spaces in between, that body didn't show in view. As I mentioned below, SQL*Plus did show correctly. New version of the tool does better, still with lot of spaces embedded, but at least within the view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to reproduce what you say is happening, and got an error:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE its_accountarray;

DECLARE
  v its_accountarray := its_accountarray();
BEGIN
  null;
END;
/

PLS-00311: the declaration of "ITS_ACCOUNTARRAY" is incomplete or malformed
```

So, you're probably looking at the wrong type definition (e.g. you're looking at it in the wrong schema), or not looking at the entire type definition (e.g. there is a TYPE BODY that provides the implementation).  Since this seems to be acting like a nested table type, the former sounds more likely.

Comment: Hi Dave, Thanks for responding so quickly.

Comment: Hi Dave, 

I think I pressed ENTER too quick last time. 

You are right!! That declaration was incorrect. I am wondering if it's a bug in the tool I was using (SqlTools 1.5). When I opened the type in SQLTools, it only showed that portion and it did not have a body! That's why I was so confused.

I just tried Describe ITS_ACCOUNTARRAY in sqlplus it shows as expected:


    `SQL> describe ITS_ACCOUNTARRAY
        ITS_ACCOUNTARRAY TABLE OF VARCHAR2(24)`


I've been using SQLTools for a few years and this is the first time, it really got me. 

Thanks a lot again.

Sam